# img <a href> link stretches to full width of parent div instead of only covering img

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

Basically, I've got a div with width set to 100%, within which there is an img link. The img's width is set to auto with a height of 600px. The link area stretches over the width of the whole div, in this case the width of the whole page, rather than just the img.

```
<div class="feature">
    <a href="feature-page.html"><img src="feature.jpg" /></a>
</div>

.feature {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.feature a img {
    width: auto;
    height: 600px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I don't want to change the div's width to a set value (which does work), because I want to be able to add images later on that may have different aspect ratios. Does anyone have a solution? thanks.

This shows the result if you set the width of the div manually: http://jsfiddle.net/L1xanprh/4/ I also tried just setting the div width to auto as well, it game the same problem as the width being 100%.

Comment: div width is 100% of what?

Answer (score 1):

For that `a`, make it's display `inline-table`

Comment: or `.feature, .feature a {display: inline-block;}`

Answer (score 0):

avoid using width:auto.
give the exact position of the image where you want to appear the image.
and use exact width and the height of the original image.
if not your image will get stretched.

If not use the width and height values with accept ratio is equal with the accept ratio of the original image.

Then your image will not get stretched. But if your using a image with lower pixel rate your image will 
blurred when your using higher width,height values than the original image.